# Creating javascript using Jade using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to create javascript using jade, I'm passing through a json object which looks like:

```
var chart = {
    type : "bar",
    values: [12, 14, 15, 16, 17],
    labels: ["aef", "aef", "aef", "aef", "aef"],
}
```

and then rendering it as

```
res.render('profile/dashboard', {chart: chart});
```

I want to place the values in the javascript file, which you would traditionally do like this

```
var doughnutData = [

    for value in charts.values
    {
        value: {value}
        color:"#F7464A"

    }

];
```

Unfortunately you cannot do that because the for function doesn't work in after 'script.', does anybody have any suggestions on how to overcome this issue? I'm trying to generate this:

```
var doughnutData = [


                {
                    value: 30,
                    color:"#F7464A"
                },
                {
                    value : 50,
                    color : "#46BFBD"
                },
                {
                    value : 100,
                    color : "#FDB45C"
                },
                {
                    value : 40,
                    color : "#949FB1"
                },
                {
                    value : 120,
                    color : "#4D5360"
                }

            ];
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Why would you want to add them to a file/inline if they're already available in the page's scope?

Comment: because i want to generate the graph dynamically, and I wont know how many values I'm going to get. So I'd like to be able to iterate over them and just generate the  {value: bla color: bla}.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an option for you:

```
  script.
     var doughnutData = [];
     [#{chart.values}].forEach(function(value){
       doughnutData.push({value: value, color:'#F7464A'});
     });
```